# How do i add Gmail API permission massively to my 300+ users?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

i've been told that my organization needs a gmail inbox but with specific features (file control, folio tracking, etc) so as i understand reading the docs i can achieve it using the Gmail API (creating drafts, searching attachment documents, etc).

But now i wonder how can i set those permissions this app will need to my 300+ clients; i saw on forums i have to do so on each account.

How can i setup "generic" API permission for those accounts (all of them have been assigned to my organization, example@organization.org.us for example)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gsuite**

If this is a Gsuite account in which case you can use a service account with domain wide deligation and gain access to all of the accounts using the service account.

**Nomral Gmail users**

Each user will have to authenticate your application once and you will get a refresh token which you should save.  You can then use the refresh token at any time to access the users account and gain access to change their permissions.